# How is Venice during COVID times?

Tags: covid-19, venice

I'm really concerned about travel now, mainly to the experience change that corona will do on travel.

About Venice specifically, how covid19 is affecting the experience as a tourist? Are the main attractions and cafes open?

Comment: What do you mean "main attractions open"? Venice is an attraction, Rialto bridge is an attraction, and the main plaza. There are open public space. If you have some museum in mind, please add it to the questions (or google it). Do you want to use "vaporetto" or going to other islands?

Comment: Quite a few [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C1ogBIv76MA) [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yeLG9jfk9lM) [that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4E9W8SGVRU0) show tourists in post-lockdown Venice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been in Venice last July, after the lockdown was lifted; it was business as usual, except for a reduced number of tourists (far fewer Americans and Chinese / oriental).

You can enter San Marco square, of course; the belltower has been open since the first days of June.

St. Mark's Basilica is still closed, but this isn't due to the Covid restrictions (it was damaged during the Acqua Alta last November). The Museum of the Basilica is open.

The various bridges (Sighs, Rialto) are open, and so are most restaurants and the traditional taverns.

Important: face masks are widespread; you'll have to wear them in all the public places, shops and restaurants. You can be refused service if you don't wear one.

Comment: (+1) St. Mark's was open last February, website is short on details, do you know when it might reopen?

Comment: Guided tours to the Basilica are suspended until further notice; one can enter from the door of the Madonna Nicopeia (on the back, next to the apse) to attend mass - and have a look around.